Tags column of Posts table changed delimiter format. Many historical queries broken. Special tag rendering also broken
To the best of my memory, and in reading my past queries- some of which I re-run on a regular basis- the format of the Tags column of the Posts table in SEDE used to be like <starball><is><so><heckin><awesome>.
However, the format seems to have recently changed to |starball|is|so|heckin|awesome|.
I suspect this to be in relation to changes with Shifting the data dump schedule: A proposal (which has already had some unintended format changes).
There are two problems with this:
Broken queries
As a result of this change, several of my queries have broken. For example, (and don't judge my pattern-matching naivity- it works well enough), detecting if a question is tagged with a git-related tag, using %<git% and %git>% (which prevents undesirable matches of tags that contain the substring "digital").
That fact alone doesn't bother me much. I can just rewrite my queries for the new format. BUT there are a lot of popular queries that may have relied on this delimitation format. If this change is kept, those will all have to be rewritten as well. I imagine that would be initially confusing to people who don't notice. I'm not sure if that would be disruptive to their rankings as they are rewritten, but I imagine it could be.
Broken display
https://data.stackexchange.com has a feature to give tag rendering for columns named [Tags] and [TagName] (see help docs). This is now broken, and would need to be updated for the format change if the format change is kept.

Assuming that this was not an accident, I for one would suggest the simplest option of reverting the format.
Outside the context of history and practicalities of history, I actually think the new format is not bad. If it had been like that from the start, I'd have no qualms with it. But... history.

That are some great tags you've found ...

@rene not as great as me (joking)

This is fixed; sorry for any inconvenience.
What happened
An inefficient scalar function that took a flattened list of tags and swapped it from one denormalized form (|tag1|tag2|) to another (<tag1><tag2>) was inadvertently skipped when running the April 14th & 21st SEDE and data dump processes.
What we're doing about it

For SEDE
I've replaced the existing module with a much more efficient inline table-valued function, and the data has been corrected across the network (Stack Overflow finished just before 06:30 UTC) for Posts. Work still in progress for PostHistory, the remaining item being PostHistoryTypeId = 9. This should be corrected by the refresh on April 28th, 2024.
status-completed
For the data dumpThis issue has already been resolved for the next data dump, but the Q1 data that's out there right now |looks|like|this|. That data set may get refreshed (and therefore corrected) sooner, as we'll be testing more improvements before then, but I don't have exact timelines.


While it may feel like we're creating more problems than we're solving, I promise that is not the case.
